# Why does the SP.SOD.executeFunc function not work properly?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jsom, jslink, sp.sod

I use this code to compare two dates, the date of today and the date in the list item. On the screen the dates look fine but when I check them in the debugger the dates are way off. Some are even one year ahead. Why does the code return a different date than what I see on the screen?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() { 
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
        OnPostRender: function (ctx) {
            // get today's date
            var today = new Date();
            var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                // get the date set in your date YourDateField
                var itemDate = new Date(rows[i]['DueDate']);
                var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
                var row = document.getElementById(rowId);
        console.log("itemdate: " + itemDate);
                if (row!=null&&itemDate <= today) {                  
                    row.style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000';                  
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a **known behavior** in SharePoint. SharePoint stores all its date/time fields in UTC time.

So, when you try to access the date values using JSOM or REST endpoints that returns the date string in a format that is specific to the regional settings of the person asking for them.

The causes and solutions for this issue are explained in detail in below article:

[SharePoint time, is not your time, is not their time](https://julieturner.net/2017/04/sharepoint-time-is-not-your-time-is-not-their-time/)

**Additional references**:

1. [SharePoint JSOM datetime values in different timezones](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/188500/sharepoint-jsom-datetime-values-in-different-timezones)

Comment: Ganesh, 
I checked the link you provided but it only tells about time differences in case of local settings. However in my case I get dates that are like somewhere in 2021 or 2022. Even the listview shows the correct dates.

Comment: Are you saying that if you enter dates from year 2020 in date-time column then it returns dates from 2021 or 2022 in your `OnPostRender` function?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what's happening.

Comment: 21-8-2020 08:30 ---->  Wed Sep 8 08:30:00 UTC+0200 2021
24-8-2020 08:00 ----> Wed Dec 8 08:00:00 UTC+0100 2021
31-7-2020 08:00 ----> Thu Jul 7 08:00:00 UTC+0200 2022
The first date is the correct one that I see in the list and the second is what I get back when I want to compare them using javascript